# NANDroid on CM12.1, Samsung Galaxy S2 I9100

Tags: cyanogenmod, recovery-mode, xposed-framework, xprivacy

I would like to install XPrivacy on CM12.1 (Samsung Galaxy S2  I9100).

For that I have to:

- Preferably do NANDroid backup
- Flash correct version of Xposed framework (`xposed-v78-sdk22-arm.zip`)
- Install Xposed app (`XposedInstaller_3.0_alpha4.apk`)

The problem is in the first point: CM was so kind as to install its own recovery, which does not provide backup option.

I used CWM recovery before, but that as far as I know isn't maintained anymore. TWRP is another option, but I can't find version for I9100 (if there is any).

What are my options?

---

I could probably stick with AppOps, but it is a bit too simple for my needs. Another question is whether it is worth the struggle with installation of XPrivacy given the stability (and security?) of such solution.

I could probably substitute some XPrivacy features with AFWall, but I had some issues installing it on CM12.1.

Another feature I would like is the access restrictions to Android ID - but that is probably possible only with Xposed(?).

Comment: Regardless of whether CWM is maintained anymore or not, have you verified that the its version [6.0.5.0](http://builder.unstableapps.com/#/all/i9100) isn't working to take backup of  CM 12.1 ROM? Furthermore, you can use `dd` to pull the images of your partitions when booted into your obsolete CWM recovery.

Comment: @Firelord I thought that the reason it was replaced was its incompatibility -> I will give CWM a try : )

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the first point [can be solved by this link on XDA.](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-nexus/general/guide-phone-backup-unlock-root-t1420351)

And by the way it is just for safety in case something happens wrongly. So, you can use that backup to get your old stable state.

Next option for you that you can flash CWM again as you have done previously to install this rom.